# How to call a function that will create an object of a class if required?

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, functional-programming, hashmap

Context:

*I've found a bug in a selenium framework I'm working on, in which the Web Browser (at least Chrome) crashes unexpectedly with no notification.

As a patch, I'm reinitializing the WebDriver so it keeps working, but right now I'm creating a new EdgeDriver and I want to create a new WebDriver of the **same type** it was before (the one that crashed).*

I came up with this approach:

```
driver = Map.of(
            ChromeDriver.class, getFunction(ChromeDriver.class),
            EdgeDriver.class, getFunction(EdgeDriver.class),
            FirefoxDriver.class, getFunction(FirefoxDriver.class),
            OperaDriver.class, getFunction(OperaDriver.class)
      ).entrySet().stream().filter((e) -> e.getKey().isInstance(driver))
      .map((e)->e.getValue().identity()).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("WebDriver not detected"));
```

...

```
@SneakyThrows
static Function<Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver>, RemoteWebDriver> getFunction(Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver> driverClass){
   return c -> {
            try {
               return c.getConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
         };
}
```

The problem is that I can't use this type of call

```
e.getValue().identity()
```

Do you know how can I achieve this?

I'm using the **Map** approach so I don't have to specify a bunch of `if`'s with all the code inside.
And I'm using a separate method returning a **Function** so I don't have to spend resources in creating the instances before (and if they) are required.

I have faced this problem before and I'm pretty sure I'm going to keep facing it, I have almost no idea what I'm writing in the functional programming section because I'm very new to it. I hope I'm on the right track but honestly, I doubt it.

*As an extra tip if you can provide a way to become an expert in functional programming in Java will be great because I've been looking for a course or any resources deep enough and I have not been able to find anything so far. Not only will solve this problem but it will help me to solve any future problems like this.*

Comment: As for the extra tip: Java kind of mixes imperative and functional styles so I'd suggest trying to learn functional programming using a purely functional language, e.g. Clojure (because it's on the JVM), and functional concepts. Once you have a good grasp of FP then apply your knowledge to what Java supports :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a factory producing WebDriver's so you would create driver for your first time and you would use the same factory for re-creating driver?

Comment: Why are you trying to call [Function.identity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) from the instance (it's static a method, creating new function)? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getFunction(Class)` returns a `Function<Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver>, RemoteWebDriver>` you'd need to call it like `e.getValue().apply(driver.getClass())`. However, `Supplier<RemoteWebDriver>` seems to be more appropriate:

```
@SneakyThrows
static Supplier<RemoteWebDriver> getSupplier(Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver> driverClass){
  return () -> {
        try {
           return driverClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
     };
}
```

Then use it like `....map((e)->e.getValue().get())`.

What did I change appart from the method name?

- return a `Supplier<RemoveWebDriver>` which has the `get()` method to execute it and return the result
- since suppliers don't take arguments the lambda changes from `c -> { ... }` to `() -> { ... }`.
- `c` is not available anymore but you'd want to "bind" the argument to `getSupplier()` to the lambda anyway which is possible since it's "effectively final". That means instead of `c.getConstructor()` you can use `driverClass.getConstructor()`

However, all that complexity isn't needed - you can just put the suppliers directly into the map:

```
//the <Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver>, Supplier<? extends RemoteWebDriver>> is needed to help the compiler infer the generic types
Map.<Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver>, Supplier<? extends RemoteWebDriver>>of(ChromeDriver.class, ChromeDriver::new, 
        EdgeDriver.class, EdgeDriver::new,
        FirefoxDriver.class, FirefoxDriver::new,
        OperaDriver.class, OperaDriver::new)
        ...
```

If you don't like this `<Class<? extends RemoteWebDriver>, Supplier<? extends RemoteWebDriver>>` you could help the compiler with a small method that has the type "baked in":

```
static Supplier<? extends RemoteWebDriver> supply(Supplier<? extends I> s) { return s ; }

Map.of(ChromeDriver.class, supply(ChromeDriver::new), 
        EdgeDriver.class, supply(EdgeDriver::new),
        FirefoxDriver.class, supply(FirefoxDriver::new),
        OperaDriver.class, supply(OperaDriver::new))
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access stored as a *Value* using method reference `Map.Entry::getValue` but it wouldn't be applicable.

Because in the `map()` you need a provide a *Function* that can dial with a `Map.Entry`, but your Function expects `Class` instance as an argument as an argument (i.e. the expected argument doesn't match).

So the correct function can be written as the following lambda expression:

```
e -> e.getValue().apply(e.getKey())
```

*Example:*

```
RemoteWebDriver target = // initializing the target driver
    
RemoteWebDriver driver = Map.of(
        ChromeDriver.class, getFunction(ChromeDriver.class),
        EdgeDriver.class, getFunction(EdgeDriver.class),
        FirefoxDriver.class, getFunction(FirefoxDriver.class),
        OperaDriver.class, getFunction(OperaDriver.class)
    )
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().isInstance(target))
    .map(e -> e.getValue().apply(e.getKey()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("WebDriver not detected"));
```